# Help with maximization problem (related to proof of Kelly Criterion)

Tags: optimization

I'm working through John Kelly's original paper that proves the "Kelly Criterion", but I'm getting hung up on one of the general proofs.  Here's a PDF of the paper.

http://turtletrader.com/kelly.pdf

On page 6 of the PDF, Kelly shows the following:

[The section I'm having trouble with in Kelly's paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxuo2.jpg)

I'm having a hard time figuring out how he solves for the maximum value of the first time.

Definitions:
p(s,r) = joint probability of the s'th transmitted and r'th received symbol

a(s/r) the fraction of a gambler's capital that he decides to bet on the occurrence of the s'th transmitted symbol after observing the r'th received symbol

p(s,r) and a(s/r) are subject to constraints:

a(s/r) > 0

the sum of a(s/r) over s = 1

p(s,r) > 0

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.  I think I'm missing something simple, but I'm stumped.